# SAX Parsing in Android Searching Attribute

Tags: java, android, xml-parsing, sax, android-xml

Im trying to identify an attribute using SAX. My XML is as follows

```
<DAY VALUE="1">
    <BREAKFAST>0700</BREAKFAST>
    <LUNCH>1200</LUNCH>
    <DINNER>1900</DINNER>
</DAY> 
<DAY VALUE="2">
    <BREAKFAST>0730</BREAKFAST>
    <LUNCH>1230</LUNCH>
    <DINNER>1930</DINNER>
</DAY>
```

and my startElement code is as follows:

```
@Override
    public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName,
            Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
        elementOn = true;
        if (localName.equals("DAY"))
        {
            data = new XMLGettersSetters();
        } 
    }
```

The above code will find the first element `"DAY"` and give me the contents but not the remaining DAY elements.

Is there a way I can search for the attribute? I am aiming to get the current day in the month and then search for the day within the xml. For example if today is the 2nd then I want to search in the XML file for `DAY VALUE="2"` and get the sub elements

==EDIT

If i modify my XML to

```
<DAY_1>
        <BREAKFAST>0700</BREAKFAST>
        <LUNCH>1200</LUNCH>
        <DINNER>1900</DINNER>
    </DAY_1> 
    <DAY_2>
        <BREAKFAST>0730</BREAKFAST>
        <LUNCH>1230</LUNCH>
        <DINNER>1930</DINNER>
    </DAY_2>
```

and code to:

```
  if (localName.equals("DAY_2"))
        {
            data = new XMLGettersSetters();
        }
```

I get a `NullPointerException` however the name if the class is not highlighted in logcat. It was referring to another class but i commented out those lines

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can get attribute value like this:

```
 if (localName.equals("DAY")){
    String day = "";
    if (attributes.getValue("VALUE") != null) {
        day = attributes.getValue("VALUE");
    }
                //data = new XMLGettersSetters();
    }
```

Comment: yes i have tried that but the app crashes when i try to use the day variable.

Comment: `if (localName.equals("DAY")){
    String day = "";
    if (attributes.getValue("VALUE") != null) {
        day = attributes.getValue("VALUE");
        System.out.println("VALUE: "+ day);
    }
      
    } `

Its getting the first <DAY VALUE=1> element with sub elements. I get 'VALUE: 1' in my log but when its going to the <DAY VALUE=2> element i am getting a NullPointer exception - Unable to start activity SAXParserActivity